# Excel: Conditionally Displaying Cells

Tags: excel, conditional-statements

I am trying to generate a user entry form that has dynamic conditional display.  In other words, when the form is first opened, I would like for certain cells to not be displayed, and then I would like to them to appear or not as the user begins to input data.  Here is what I currently have:

[image]

Based off of whether or not the user chooses "Days" or "Hours" from the box in C3, I would like for rows 6 through 8 to be hidden.  Likewise, if the user chooses "Hours", then rows 9 through 11 should be hidden.  This is what I wrote so far:

```
    Sub ConditionalDisplay ()
    BeginRow = 1
    EndRow = 50

    For RowCnt = BeginRow to EndRow

    IF Cells(RowCnt, CheckColumn).Value = "Days" THEN
       Rows("6:8").EntireRow.Hidden = TRUE
    ELSE
        Rows("6:8").EntireRow.Hidden = FALSE
    END IF

    Next RowCnt
    End Sub
```

This does not work.  Even if it did, I think this would require the user having to manually run this macro every time he/she opens this workbook, which is something that needs to be avoided.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You never declared `CheckColumn` - what's it going to be? Also, look into a `Workbook_Open()` event, if you want to hide certain cells on open.

Comment: `worksheets("Calculator").Rows("6:8").Hidden = worksheets("Calculator").Range("C3") = "Days"` and `worksheets("Calculator").Rows("9:11").Hidden = worksheets("Calculator").Range("C3") = "Hours"`

Comment: @BruceWayne sorry about that...CheckColumn = 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this code in a module attached to the workbook

```
Sub ConditionalDisplay()
    With Worksheets("Calculator")
        IF .Range("C3") <> "Days" And .Range("C3") <> "Hours" Then
            .Rows("6:11").Hidden = True
        Else
            .Rows("6:8").Hidden = .Range("C3") = "Days"
            .Rows("9:11").Hidden = .Range("C3") = "Hours"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Then in the worksheet code for `Calculator` put this event code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C3")) Is Nothing Then
    ConditionalDisplay
End If
End Sub
```

Then in the ThisWorkbook Code put this event:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Worksheets("Calculator").Range("C3") = ""
ConditionalDisplay
End Sub
```

Comment: Would you be able to give a little rundown of what the function is for each of these sections you mentioned?  The first one and last one make sense, but I'm not sure I follow what's going on in the code for the `Calculator` worksheet.

Comment: The second one fires the sub whenever the cell C3 changes on sheet `Calculator`.  So if one were to change C3 from `Days` to `Hours` the code would fire and unhide row 6:8 and hide rows 9:11.  This is a worksheet event and when any cell on that sheet changes it runs.  It will check if Cell C3 is the one that changed, if not it ignores the rest of the code, but if so it calls `ConditionalDisplay`

Comment: Interesting.  What is that "If Not Intersect" argument?  I've never seen that one before.  I really don't play around too much in VBA, but I'd really like to.  It's very powerful if you know it.

Comment: Also, I was thinking of ways to modify this to make a little more user friendly (for the user I mean)....is there a way to have it so that the "Number of days in period/Number of hours in period" box doesn't show up at all until the user makes a selection?  In other words, when the user opens the form, C3 has no value until they make a choice and thus the "Number of days in period" or "Number of hours in period" doesn't show up until they make a choice.

Comment: If Target, which is the cell that caused the event to fire, intersects with C3 then it would return a range, in this case C3.  Otherwise it returns nothing.  So we test if it is something, a range and if so it call the sub.  If there is no intersection then it returns nothing and the if statement is false.

Comment: Now you are starting to modify the question. I have modified the answer past the original question. See edit @Ryan_C

Comment: Very interesting.  What were some resources you used when you were originally learning VBA?

Comment: This site mainly. Then trial and error as I learned to ask the correct questions in google search. @Ryan_C

Comment: Thanks.  I hope I'm not asking stupid questions.  Just trying to learn :)

Comment: @Ryan_C just remember to mark as correct if it works for you.

Comment: Interesting problem happening: the workbook is opening as intended; however, whenever I choose "Days" or "Hours", rows 6-8 AND rows 9-11 are displaying now.  Further, whenever I change the selection it won't hide the appropriate rows.  Any ideas?

Comment: I am in a meeting I know what it is. I will fix later tonight.

Comment: Okay...I think it is in the "Intersect" portion of the code, but I may be wrong.

Comment: @Ryan_C See edit.  The problem was my hastily added code to show none till C3 had a choice.

Comment: What exactly was happening with older version to cause it not display properly?

Comment: I had the third line was overriding the hides and unhiding everything.  Now if it does not have Days or Hours in C3 then all is hidden.

Comment: If I wanted to expand on this so that only one user entry cell pops up at a time, then I would simply need to add a series of additional "Else If" statements, correct?

Comment: Try it and if you get stuck open another question.